# Multi-level menu with tabs and columns

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation

I want to create a menu in footer looking like:

```
    MODA            ELEKTRONIKA        USŁUGI            (1)
-----\/-----      ---------------    ----------     

Odzież         Buty        Sport             Dodatki     (2)

Crapp          Exco        The South Race    Vista       (3)
Horse          Gojas       Goo Snort         Ray-Bahn
Deserved       Dojczman    Basics            Chino Russi
Nara           Nice
Mosquito       E-book
```

It consists of:

1. Tabs - each tab contains its own columns
2. Columns - each column contains its own menu links
3. Menu links

All of them should be managed from admin panel. How to achieve it? I installed [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) [QuickTabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) but editing such menus may last very long. [QuickTabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module lets you to manage tabs but how to manage columns and links? You can create multiple-level menus. However, column headers should NOT be clickable.

Is it possible to do it using existing modules or should I create my own module?

Comment: Did you see this: https://www.drupal.org/node/523868 ?

Comment: Also look here: [How to show and configure the footer mega-menu](https://www.drupal.org/node/1415698)